# SQL - use CSV from variable in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a concatenation of multiple columns.

For example, if this would be my table:

```
IntA   IntB   IntC   IntD
1      21     31     201601
2      35     88     201602
```

*all columns are of datatype bigint, except IntD, which is always present and is Int.*

I would like to calculate an 'CalculatedCol' column that will concatenate some of the columns as a string, like so;

```
cast(IntA as nvarchar(3)) + cast(IntB nvarchar(3)) + cast(IntD nvarchar(3)) 
AS CalculatedCol
```

Output being:

```
IntA   IntB   IntC   IntD     CalculatedCol
1      21     31     201601   121201601
2      35     88     201602   235201602
```

The tricky part is that the columns used in determining CalculatedCol are different (depending on which client is using the system). I get these columns from another table and have it stored in a variable as CSV string, i.e.:

```
@columns = IntA,IntB,IntD
```

This is where I'm stuck- is it possible to use this variable and take the columns it specifies between the commas? I'm not sure where to begin even.

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if dynamic SQL is what you want, but you can do:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = '
select ' + @columns + ', concat(' + @columns + ') as CalculatedCol
from t
';

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: that work like a charm. Dynamic is fine in my use case. thanks.